# How to retrieve part of a text of an element using Selenium WebDriver and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver and Python 3 and I'm trying to retrieve part of the text of the element.

```
<div id="ConfirmInfo" class="row">
                    <h3>Confirmation #: S1234567890 </h3>
</div>
```

How can I retrieve just "S1234567890" without "Confirmation #: "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
element_text = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h3').text
#split element_text into ['Confirmation', '#:', 'S1234567890']
split_text = element_text.split(' ') 
confirmation_num = split_text[2]
```

Selenium provides you with tools to get the text from an element, but if you want to get only a part of the text from the element, AFAIK you have to get the text from the element and then manipulate the string until you have the part you want.